# Can i use this wifi router to EXTEND my existing wifi LAN at home?

Tags: wireless-networking

i have a wifi network at home -> works well. I think it's set up to use WPA-SPK or whatever that funky wifi protocol is. (But i can change that, if required).

Anyways, it only gets to half of the house because of interference (eg. fridges). So, i was hoping to *extend* the home wifi network.

The IT guys at work have a spare D-Link DI-634M router modem wifi thingy.

[image]

Can I use this to extend my home wifi network? If so, what are the key settings i would need to check/change/tweak? I've never done this before.

I've also found this [Emulator](http://support.dlink.com/Emulators/di634m/) on their website, if that helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at **[network bridging](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/1563991)**. **[Linksys device here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008WMBT)**

You might want to look to see if your device can be flashed to use [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php) instead. That firmware has great support for doing network bridging with consumer hardware routers.

**edit:** your device isn't supported unfortunately. However, many linksys devices are and the dd-wrt firmware provides much functionality for free. Further googling revealed that your device doesn't support bridging at all.

Comment: Can it support dd-wrt though? how do i know if it does/doesn't?

Comment: There is a supported device list here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices